# Why can't a class inherit from the result of a decltype?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, decltype

Why can't a class have a `decltype` in the inheritance list? For instance, I would expect the following code to make `A<B>` inherit from `RType`, but with G++ 4.6.1 (using `-std=c++0x`) it does not compile:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class A : public decltype(std::declval<T>().hello()) { };

class RType { };

class B {
public:
    RType hello() { return RType(); }
};

int main() {
    A<B> a;
}
```

It gives the following output:

```
test.cpp:6:18: error: expected class-name before 'decltype'
test.cpp:6:18: error: expected '{' before 'decltype'
test.cpp:6:54: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:16:7: error: aggregate 'A<B> a' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

The use of `declval` is just to provide an instance where you needed to use `decltype`, but other uses of `decltype` also fail (that is, without `declval`).

Comment: Have you tried gcc 4.7, clang or any other compiler? gcc isn't fully C++11 compliant yet...

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'm actually trying to compile clang now (for other reasons) but with MSVC++ 2010 it doesn't work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's allowed :

10.1 : "A list of base classes can be specified in a class definition using the notation:"

```
class-or-decltype:
nested-name-specifieropt class-name
decltype-specifier
```

so I guess your compiler has bug

Comment: Eclipse CDT also report this as a syntax error but in fact, it compiles.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like [a bug in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42603). Try 4.7.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround:

```
template <typename T>
class ID
{
 public:
  typedef T type;
};

template<typename T>
class A : public ID<whatever>::type { };
```

Comment: Notice that I'm inheriting from the type that is the return type of a function. This doesn't/can't do the same thing.

Comment: @Seth : I think the implication was to try `template<typename T> class A : public ID<decltype(std::declval<T>().hello())>::type { };`.

Comment: And instead of writing your own class you can use `std::enable_if<true, decltype(...)>::type`

Comment: I think an identity transformation is important enough, it should be defined separately and called by its proper name.

Comment: @n.m. Boost has it: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/identity.html

Answer (score -2):

You might try something like

```
template<typename T>
class A : public result_of<T::hello()>
```

though it may be expecting a static member function for that syntax, and it would likely run into the same bug that prevents decltype from working.